# Find Rows Where Column Value Contain in a String

Tags: pandas

Example:

```
data='findme, ok'
df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in data.split('\n')])
df.columns = ['keyword', 'result']
keywords = df['keyword'].tolist()
test1='maybe you canfindme'.lower()
```

How can I convert the below syntax to dataframe syntax?

```
for keyword in df['keyword'].tolist():
    if keyword in test1:
        print(keyword)
```

Of course this is wrong, but I am looking for something like this:

```
filter_result = df[df['keyword'] in test1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to use the `map` method.

See [Map method documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

In your case:

```
df[df['keyword'].map(lambda k: k in test1)==True]
```

Comment: @BryanFok Is `== True` necessary?